# Нет конекта к MongoDB через pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

поднял контейнр
docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27021:27021
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
```

пробую подключиться к БД через pymongo, но конект не происходит получаю ошибку:

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: connection closed, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 5f7f2b5f8ba7181b5ec82b55, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27021) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('connection closed')>]>
```

через mongo-express вижу БД и могу с ней работать.

вот код на py:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient("mongodb://root:example@localhost:27021/")
db = client["admin"]
col = db["system.users"]
x = col.find_one()
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Кажется проблема была в том что пробрасывал не тот порт на котором поднимается MongoDB
попробовал 27017 и все заработало